How to Determine the Center of Two Curvilinear Lines and Display the Points on a Windows Form Picture Box using OpenCV?
I'm trying to find a way to determine the centre point between two lines, at different positions, using OpenCV in C#. In Roborealm, I achieved this using the edge_probe technique, as illustrated in the second image. Now, I want to replicate this functionality in C# using OpenCV with the first image. I need multiple centre points so that I can get an average value for the centre, because the lines aren't straight.
As I'm new to OpenCV, I'd appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to approach this problem. Additionally, since I'm working with a Windows form application, I'm interested in any suggestions related to displaying the edge points and center points, similar to how I did it in Roborealm.
Thank you in advance for any help or insights you can provide!
opencv:

Roborealm:

This is what I've done up to this point to get the first image.
Mat image = CvInvoke.Imread("C:\\Image_2.png");
Mat kernel1 = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ElementShape.Rectangle, new Size(3, 3), new Point(1, 1));

CvInvoke.CvtColor(image, image, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
CvInvoke.MedianBlur(image, image, 9);
CvInvoke.Threshold(image, image, 100, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);
CvInvoke.MorphologyEx(image, image, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.MorphOp.Close, kernel1, new Point(0, 0), 6, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar());
CvInvoke.Canny(image, image, 50, 200);

pictureBox1.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image.ToBitmap(), image.Width, image.Height);
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;


you'll want to reimplement this "edge probe" thing. you can sample an image along arbitrary lines and step sizes using a custom affine matrix and warpAffine. in the horizontal case, you can also just slice samples out of the Mat. now you have an 1D profile signal along such a line. then you just need to calculate the gradient in each sample (using preceding and succeeding sample) and find the extremum of that. or just find where the 1D profile signal crosses a threshold.

Thank you @ChristophRackwitz for your response. I will definitely give this a try. Do you perhaps have a suggestion on how I could display a "square" or "circle" to visually indicate the edges, similar to how Roborealm does?

opencv has functions for drawing rectangles and circles into a Mat. if the Mat is grayscale but you want to draw with colors, I'd recommend cvtColor to BGR first.
